# Why does the Oracle database query (Long datatype in Oracle database table's column) not execute in QueryDatabaseTable Apache Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a Oracle database with a column setup as '`long`' data type. The column has `XML` data. I am trying to transfer the data from Oracle to Bigquery.

I tried the following setup and it worked perfectly:

```
ExecuteSQL -> AvroToJson ->PutBigQueryBatch
```

However when I tried to do a incremental load with the following setup, it threw an error:

```
QueryDatabaseTable -> AvroToJson ->PutBigQueryBatch
```

I tried to look into the issue and found the Github [support request](https://github.com/apache/nifi/commit/68a49cfad04df2f467f9529c0fc1b6daf1781192) which is resolved. Is this bug or is there a mistake I make?

Error:

```
2020-01-14 19:24:56,184 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-41] o.a.n.p.standard.QueryDatabaseTable QueryDatabaseTable[id=016f11ea-e0e7-1523-fbf7-428dad259c96] Unable to execute SQL select query SELECT * FROM (select * from table) table due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Error during database query or conversion of records.: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Error during database query or conversion of records.
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Error during database query or conversion of records.
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AbstractQueryDatabaseTable.lambda$onTrigger$0(AbstractQueryDatabaseTable.java:295)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.write(StandardProcessSession.java:2730)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AbstractQueryDatabaseTable.onTrigger(AbstractQueryDatabaseTable.java:291)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1176)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Stream has already been closed
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.sql.DefaultAvroSqlWriter.writeResultSet(DefaultAvroSqlWriter.java:51)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AbstractQueryDatabaseTable.lambda$onTrigger$0(AbstractQueryDatabaseTable.java:293)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Stream has already been closed
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.LongAccessor.getBytesInternal(LongAccessor.java:156)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.LongAccessor.getBytes(LongAccessor.java:126)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.LongAccessor.getString(LongAccessor.java:201)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CLongAccessor.getString(T4CLongAccessor.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getObject(CharCommonAccessor.java:788)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getObject(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1026)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getObject(DelegatingResultSet.java:733)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getObject(DelegatingResultSet.java:733)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.db.JdbcCommon.convertToAvroStream(JdbcCommon.java:337)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.sql.DefaultAvroSqlWriter.writeResultSet(DefaultAvroSqlWriter.java:49)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

I tried to set `Normalise Table/ Column Names` along with `Avro Logical Type` to both `True` and `False` in all four combinations, it still threw an error. Is there any known fix for this?

Comment: try to convert XML to CLOB in your sql query

Comment: Since it is a 'Long' datatype, I could not do any casting. @daggett

Comment: XMLTYPE.getclobval() https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb04cre.htm

Comment: or xmlserilize ()  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions239.htm#SQLRF06231

Comment: @daggett I made a mistake in the question. The datatype is not 'XMLtype' but 'Long'. The 'Long' datatype column have XML data (Irrelevant).

Comment: Have you seen this: Do not create tables with LONG columns. Use LOB columns (CLOB, NCLOB) instead. LONG columns are supported only for backward compatibility. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1831

Comment: possibly there is a problem with LONG datatype in nifi. What exact version of nifi do you have? I could suggest script as workaround.

Comment: try to use `TO_LOB(LONG_COL)` to convert long column to clob

Comment: I use Apache Nifi Release 1.10.0 (I believe this is the latest one available now for download). I saw the feature request for Long support in Apache issues page, they since added from I believe Apache Nifi release 1.6. ExecuteSQL is able to get the data though, just not the QueryDatabaseTable processor. @daggett

Comment: It is a production DB where I only have access to read the data. I have requested to alter the schema using TO_LOB but the request got thrown out.

Comment: use function to_lob in your select

Comment: I've got an error if I use 'select to_lob(long_column) from table'. 
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got LONG. @daggett

Answer (score 0):

According to a blog from the creator of the JOOQ database system, the root cause of this issue is that, bizarrely, any LONG and LONG RAW rows need their data to be fetched before all other rows. This is due to a weird quirk in either the Oracle JDBC drivers, or the underlying actual operations going on in the database.

Here's the blog on the subject:

https://blog.jooq.org/oracle-long-and-long-raw-causing-stream-has-already-been-closed-exception/

Note, I am in no way affiliated with JOOQ; it's just the only place I found which has a clear explanation on why this problem occurs. Thankfully, in my own case, the database table could be changed to convert its problematic LONG column to BLOB type instead.